# In Android how do you create Swipeable views inside each tab of a tab layout?

Tags: java, android

I want to create tabs that the user swipes left and right between, but the user should also swipe left and right between the views that are within a tab. When the user has swiped to the final view within a tab then the next swipe will take him to the next tab. Here's an illustration: [Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EteDK.png)

I've already created an app using the Android Studio Tabs activity template that uses ViewPager and TabLayout. I can't find any example of how this is supposed to be done. Does anyone have an example or just general idea of how it should be implemented? Thank you.